# Imperfect Jquery animations timings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").fadeOut(500);
    count++;
    $("#test").fadeIn(500);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = count;
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: gold;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span id="test">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Jquery. In the above code, the number inside the div increments on clicking and fades out and in. I want it to work such that the existing number disappears first and then the next number appears while, here, the number first changes and then fades out and in, which is not how I want it to work. Please run the snippet to see the problem. What is wrong or missing in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it takes the `fadeOut` 500 ms but the increment of `count` and the assignment happens right away. You can use the callback [**`complete`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) of `fadeOut` to achieve what you need:

```
$("#test").fadeOut(500, function() { // the function will be called when the fadeOut is completed
    count++;                         // increment count
    this.textContent = count;        // assign it to this element (#test) textContent
}).fadeIn(500);                      // then fadeIn
```

```js
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").fadeOut(500, function() {
        count++;
        this.textContent = count;
    }).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: gold;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span id="test">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer and the answer below both work correctly for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
you need to increment in callback of fading out, meaning increment when animation is complete

```js
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").fadeOut(500, function(){
      count++;
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = count;
      }
    );
  
    $("#test").fadeIn(500);
    
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: gold;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span id="test">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer works correctly for me and the other two above also do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div").on("click", function() {
count++;
  $("#test").fadeOut(500).$("test").text(count).fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

"JQuery Chaining"
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

Comment: Thanks for your effort and for info about JQuery Chaining.